# как в React компонента react-router-dom генерировать link по id(to который href) и компонент куда

Tags: reactjs

id приходит с json а эта ссылка в map нужно что бы каждый раз когда по нему проходит, она добовляла ссылку(это она делает) только немогу сделать в какой компонент переходить

```
<Link className="btn btn-red bottonmore" to={id}    >  Посмотреть больше</Link>
```

Comment: чтобы получилось <Link className="btn btn-red bottonmore" to={id}    component="About">  Посмотреть больше</Link>

Answer (score 1):

Для начала вы должны добавить Route, который будет отрисовывать ваш компонент. Например:

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/some_path/:id" component={MyComponent} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

Тогда ссылка будет такая:

```
<Link to={`/some_path/${id}`}>Click Me</Link>
```

По клику на ссылку или прямому переходу из строки браузера, будет отрисован компонент MyComponent. id можно будет получить в компоненте как:

```
const MyComponent = ({ match }) => {
  const { id } = match.params;

  return (/* ... */);
}
```